# Is there a way for a bot to detect a users unique device id in discord.js/node.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm about to host a competition where you register via a bot in discord.
And I want to prevent users from submitting and then logging out and in again with a different account and submitting again. And doing that maybe 20 times to get a bigger chance to win.

If there is some way to detect that they are using the same device and make the following submissions invalid?

If not, if someone has a smart idea to prevent multiple submissions?

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js does not have a way to track an specific device *yet*.

Something clever you could do, is to make the bot give your users a link to make them register via a website that stores a cookie to tell whether you have signed up already or not. You can also use [Discord's OAuth2](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#oauth2) to get the information from your signed up users to your database.

Comment: I decided to go with a combination of:
$computerId = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].$_SERVER['LOCAL_ADDR'].$_SERVER['LOCAL_PORT'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

and setting a cookie.

Hopefully, it will bring down the number of multiple submissions.

Comment: @HappyQuokka that is great to know. Wish you luck in your task!